# Stop an Azure ContainerApp?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have an Azure ContainerApp deployed with a single revision, and I'd like to stop it - but not delete it and have to re-deploy it.  I see the image in the registry, and there are options via the portal to deploy it to an AppService or ContainerInstance, but not to a ContainerApp.

I also have looked through the az CLI, specifically [az containerapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest), but see no way to stop a running instance.  I can set the scale to 0-1, but it still runs.

Am I missing something?  Stopping an instance seems like a pretty normal thing to do...

**EDIT** - Setting all revisions to inactive doesn't seem to be allowed.  See images below.

[image: Revisions]

[image: Save Revisions]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update: there is now a proper way to stop, see the answer by HQT

---

You can deactivate a revision to shut down the containers. If you deactivate all active revisions, you will effectively stop your containerapp.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/application-lifecycle-management

> Once a revision is no longer needed, you can deactivate a revision with the option to reactivate later. During deactivation, containers in the revision are shut down.

When you need it again, you can use `activate` to get new replicas.

```
az containerapp revision deactivate --resource-group
                                    --revision
                                    [--name]

az containerapp revision activate --resource-group
                                  --revision
                                  [--name]
```

If you visit the containerapp url after deactivating all revisions, you will receive an error:

> Error 403 - This Container App is stopped.

Comment: Deactivating all active revisions doesn't seem to be allowed.  See edited question above.

Comment: @pseabury it works using the CLI, I tested it when I posted the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex-ait, that indeed did work.  It'd be helpful if the portal and the CLI were synced.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Using this method, in my case the revision gets reactivated after roughly 3 days. Stopping the container app through the REST API (and Portal/CLI soon) should be the way to go going forward (See @HQT 's answer).

Answer (score 5):

(july 2023) still can't be done via the portal unfortunately, BUT the ACA dev team just implemented start and stop requests (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/664#issuecomment-1632897821)), that's neat :

```
az rest -m POST -u "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.App/containerapps/$APP_NAME/start?api-version=2023-04-01-preview"
az rest -m POST -u "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.App/containerapps/$APP_NAME/stop?api-version=2023-04-01-preview"
```

Answer (score 4):

In azure portal if you go to container you have ready to use cli commands under Automation section.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be new sometime in H2 2023 - good to know!