Set auto-shutdown for my Container App on Azure
I have a Container App that has Scale, and I need it to automatically shut down at night, like from 22pm to 7:00am. How can this be done? Because I have not found anything about it but I understand that it can be done.
I have seen that I can stop and start the Conatiner with: Stop-AzContainerApp -Name -ResourceGroupName
But, how I can execute that sentence from my linux terminal?

Maybe you can configure a pipeline that runs on a schedule to do that? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750192/stop-an-azure-containerapp

I would be lost to do that, any help from the CLI?

From the azure portal, you can find the Azure PowerShell command to start/stop the container app.

Then we can run the command in the Azure PowerShell task of Azure DevOps pipelines with Scheduled triggers. If you haven't used the Azure DevOps pipeline before, you can start by browsing the related documentation.
Here is the yaml pipeline for your reference:
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 22 * * *"
  displayName: 'Shutdown Schedule'
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true
- cron: "0 7 * * *"
  displayName: 'Startup Schedule'
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

jobs:
- job: Shutdown
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'), eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'Shutdown Schedule'))
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'your service connection name'
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      Inline: 'Stop-AzContainerApp -Name yourContainerAppname -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroupname -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

- job: Startup
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'), eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'Startup Schedule'))
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'your service connection name'
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      Inline: 'Start-AzContainerApp -Name yourContainerAppname -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroupname -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'


The pipeline will run the stop job at 22pm and the start job at 7am.


But the pipeline is with Github code, and that is a Container app. I cant do that

Hi @JuanCarlosGonzalezQuesada , do you mean your code is on GitHub? In fact, Azure Pipeline can use GitHub as the source code and use Scheduled triggers. I'm not sure what you are emphasizing when you say "that is a Container app", can you explain it in detail? Is it that you don't want or can't use Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Hi @miao-tian-msft yes, I just remembered that I do indeed have the Node app on github and that I call the CLI. The thing is, they don't work, or I don't know how to run the CLI you passed me in the DevOps Pipelines.... It always gives an error

I would prefer not to use azure devops, and use something like contab on Linux. I don't know how to use Azure very much and that makes me unable to move forward.

Hi @JuanCarlosGonzalezQuesada, to run the Azure PowerShell command (Stop-AzContainerApp and Start-AzContainerApp) on Linux, you should Install Azure PowerShell on Linux first.  Then you can try to use Cron to run these commands. By the way, if you are willing to try azure pipeline and have some questions when using it, I will be happy to help you.

Yes @miao-tian-msft yes, I installed that, but with crontab is not possible to log-in. Always expose and error

Dou you mean you got error when login with Connect-AzAccount? Or can you share the error message？
